# Adding html target attribute to APEX tree link

Tags: html, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I use a tree for navigation in an Oracle APEX app, and use the "Link Column" setting for navigation.

Although, I would like to use the `<a>` tag attributes (`target="_blank"`, for instance). The Link column only sets the `href` attribute to the link.

I would like to use another column in my table to set it as the target or other tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link attributes on a tree don't support the target attribute. If you want the link to open a new window/tab you can change the link to run javascript to open the target. Set Target Type = **URL**, and set the URL to:

```
javascript:window.open("...link to page...","_blank")
```

e.g. if your query has a column called `LINK_URL`:

```
javascript:window.open("&LINK_URL.","_blank")
```

Comment: I used:

 `javascript:window.open("#URL#","_blank")`

as it my column is named `URL`, but console returns me this error:

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #URL#`

I also tried with a fix URL, and it those open it on a new window, but replaces my current window with a blank :

`[object Window]`

where the link is simply the `javascript:window.open(...)`

Comment: Using `javascript:window.open("&URL.","_blank")`, works for referencing my colum's value instead of `#URL#`, I also ended up caling my own JavaScript function instead of `window.open()`, which fixed my `[object Window]` problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep, I forgot the tree uses the older syntax. The newer reports use `#URL#` syntax for referring to column values.